# Spotify Play Button and Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, spotify

I'm trying to track clicks in the Spotify Play Button iframe using Google Analytics, without much success so far. I'm attempting to use jQuery to capture the click.

The code

```
$('iframe .clickable.play-pause-btn').click(function(){
    alert('foo');
});
```

obviously doesn't work as it's cross domain. Is there any alternative that can capture these clicks? Or do I just live safe in the knowledge that I'll never know how many users hit play?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the cross domain policy wont let you track an event on an element inside an iframe that's running on a different domain.

I dont think we have a solution to send tracking info to the parent window.